# How to bring MKMapView top on MKPolygonView

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I am adding coloured polygons of all country boundaries shape on MKMapView,but my problem is that I want after adding polygons on map the names of cities and places should look clear and top of the polygon with fully visible polygons i added.

I already set alpha value to half of MKPolygonView to show both coloured polygons on map as well as name are too visible but by doing this names are behind polygons,my client needs names should be on top on polygons with fully non transparent coloured polygons.

I googled so much no got appropriate answer for this problem.

If anyone have solution the I highly admire it.

I hope you got my Query and got it fully if not then pls let me know So I can elaborate it as I need solution as ASAP.

Comment: [PolygonView bringSubviewToFront:MapView];

Comment: This is my answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397796/is-there-a-way-to-draw-under-names-in-mkmapview/15680042#15680042